# Fetch response and parse to json getting html instead of the JSON data at the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, fetch-api

I am clearly getting HTML here and I can't understand why exactly. This is the function that's expected to fetch the data and parse the URL to json but even though the console shows the URL when using [console.log(res)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC6Jh.png) when I try res.json() I get a [rejected promise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQJue.png)

```
const fetchData = async () => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        setLat(position.coords.latitude);
        setLong(position.coords.longitude);
      });

      await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&APPID=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
      .then(res => console.log(res)) //expected URL appears in the console. 
      
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [lat,long])
```

> I **tried** res.text() to see the response that's being fetched and >concluded that I am getting the HTML file from the public directory. (I >assumed it was HTML considering the unexpected token.) I don't understand >why it's not parsing to JSON and instead, it's fetching the HTML. [console HTML info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znpuq.png) I see this in the console but am not sure what to do from here

Also in the console of the app I checked fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=28.052684799999998&lon=-82.427904&APPID=d8c1409b5342d12f52e6dce35fc26aac') and a pending promise was returned. [console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAEKF.png)

I uploaded the [repo](https://github.com/JelenaMF/weather-app) for better understanding
Is there some confusion happening because of the environmental variables?

Comment: The data that's returned is not JSON. It's something other than JSON.

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        setLat(position.coords.latitude);
        setLong(position.coords.longitude);
      });` is asynchronous.... your lat and lng are not going to be set

Comment: Write `fetch(url).then(response => response.text()).then(console.log)` in the console to view the response. It says the response begins with `<`, therefore it's most likely either XML or HTML, rather than JSON. One of the possible explanations is that the API serves XML by default, and you forgot to add the `Accept: application/json` header. Nevertheless, console.logging the response should show you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As I know nothing about the url you are about to fetch, I can only guess that you have error in the url format and the backend `reject` you. Even if the server sends json data in normal situation, if you have an error in your url, it will send error pages like server error, 404 error, things like that.

Copy and paste the url in the new browser tab and check the response. I think you might get a error page.

Comment: I've copied and pasted the URL several times and I get the json that I'm expecting. That's why I'm confused. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Because the document Your fetching is in HTML format Not in JSON format

**HTML**

Start's with `<!DOCTYPE html>` (brackets) {throws Error}

**JSON**

```json
format : {"latitude":"-0289201019", "longitude":"-0289201019"}
```

Use the `res.text()` to debug

Comment: @JelenaFeliciano Have you read the contents of the HTML? It might contain a helpful message.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems to be a little complicated as I could not get the result like you. But I think there is a way.

As you mentioned that it is returning HTML format, first convert it to html using this.

```
var html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/xml")
```

`html.documentElement` will return `HTML` like this.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
```

Use console.log to see the result. If the `json` string is in the body, you can use normal `javascript` functions to get results.

For example, you can get `body` content using

`html.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a solution, but there are a few issues with [your current code](https://github.com/JelenaMF/weather-app/blob/ec1e7cdbe0e8962bdb67cf70374f6ded80e3a509/src/App.js#L15-L32).

> ```
> //create two states for longitude and latitude
> const [lat, setLat] = useState([]);
> const [long, setLong] = useState([]);
> //const [data, setData] = useState([]);
>
> useEffect(() => {
>   const fetchData = async () => {
>     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
>       setLat(position.coords.latitude);
>       setLong(position.coords.longitude);
>     });
>
>     await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&APPID=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
>     .then(res => console.log(res))
>   
>   }
>   fetchData();
> }, [lat,long])
> ```

1. Why use an empty array as default state for `lat` and `long`? Latitude and longitude are numbers. Either represent them as `0`, or use `null` to represent that the value is not yet loaded.

   ```
   const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);
   const [lon, setLon] = useState(null);
   ```

   I will be using `null` to represent an unloaded value.
2. `useEffect(callback, [lat, lon])` will be triggered whenever `lat`, `lon`, or both change. You will then call `getCurrentPosition()` and override the changed values. That isn't a logical thing to do. Loading the current position is a good starting position, but whenever a user change `lat` or `lon` I assume you want fetch the weather of the provided location.

   You are currently overriding `lat`/`lon` with the current location each time `lat`/`lon` change. The best thing here is split up the actions:

   ```
   // load the current location only on component mount as starting point
   useEffect(() => {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       setLat(position.coords.latitude);
       setLon(position.coords.longitude);
     });
   }, []); // <- empty dependency list

   // retrieve new weather info each time lat or lon changes
   useEffect(() => {
     // Make sure both lat and lon are present before firing a fetch request.
     // Can't use truthy/falsy because 0 is a valid coordinate, but is falsy.
     if (lat == null) return;
     if (lon == null) return;

     fetch(`.../weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&...`)
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(data => console.log(data));
   }, [lat, lon]); // <- having lat/lon as dependencies
   ```

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-react-by-building-a-weather-app/  I was following this article to practice fetching API's. Which is why I ended up adding empty arrays to the useState. Thanks for your helpful response